# Quiz creator and sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Hi there i want to use a quiz creator software like [quiz creator](http://www.wondershare.com/pro/quizcreator.html) or articulate
My problem is that i want to save quiz results to sharepoint lists.
like : quizname : xx
quiztaker: yy
quiztime : x
correct answers: 5
wrong answers : 7 etc.

Is there any way to achieve this,or is there any open source .net quiz maker like these utilities to save the results in a custom place like sql server or sp lists.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is... saving data to SharePoint lists?

Comment: yes,want to save quiz results to a custom sp list

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking to achieve something like this, [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) is a jQuery library that makes SharePoint's web services easier to use. It has helped some people achieve some very nice functionality, like a [Custom Quizzing System](http://sympmarc.com/2013/02/13/spservices-stories-6-custom-quizzing-system/). The original author worked with the developer of SPServices to get this feature working for a school environment. It is an HTML page with JavaScript and jQuery that saves the results to a SP List.

You'll need to make some major modifications to it (ie. update references to .js libs, replace all instances of document.write, etc.) but with some work you could achieve what you're looking for, and probably more.